# Connecting Eclipse JGit to GitHub, so TeamCity may check for changes

Tags: github, rsa, teamcity, jsch, jgit

GitHub has engaged its [2nd phase of SSH protocol security](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/), where they disable using SHA-1 with RSA keys. The OpenSSH client works OK with the RSA keys, but the `org.jgit` one inside TeamCity is working no longer, getting:

> Failed to collect changes, error: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: git@github.com:Project/Repository.git: ERROR: You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type.

How do I instruct TeamCity not using SHA-1 and using supported hashing instead?

I could possibly migrate to Ed25519 key, but it is not supported by our Windows agents, and I have to change all keys in the TeamCity once more, meaning I will have two problems.

Is there a practical way to make TeamCity friends with SSH RSA keys for GitHub in 2022? For reference, I am on `2021.2.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity now has versions out that properly work with RSA key using SHA-512, which GitHub will accept.  Older version of TeamCity prefers `ssh-rsa` over `rsa-sha2-512` and `rsa-sha2-256`, unlike most other clients, so they will always try to log in with the insecure SHA-1-based RSA signatures when using an RSA key and get this message.  OpenSSH prefers the SHA-2-based signatures first, and so it works.

If you use the latest version, 2021.2.3, or newer, then you should be able to use an RSA key without problems.  Ed25519 keys or ECDSA keys may also be able to work properly, although older versions may also have bugs in them.

Comment: Ed25519 or ECDSA keys also do not seem to work due to a bug in JSch.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that TeamCity now has fixed versions out.  You'd need to use the very latest version, which I have seen at least some evidence happens to work.

Comment: That's great to hear. Unfortunately, the general problem with JGit seems to remain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532284/how-to-use-jgit-with-github-in-2022 - I wonder how they fixed that.

Comment: They used a fork.  I just answered that question.