# How to use JGit with GitHub in 2022

Tags: java, github, jsch, jgit

In 2022, GitHub has discontinued DSA and RSA with old signatures.

Unfortunately, JGit uses JSch which is not getting any updates and will [always offer old signatures with RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70668289/connecting-eclipse-jgit-to-github-so-teamcity-may-check-for-changes) even for "good" keys, and its implementation of [ECDSA/ed25519 will fail on reconnect attempt](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093889/).

Is JGit usable with GitHub at all - what kind of configuration should I use? I am talking about a combination of key type, configuration settings and code invocations that would lead to reliable work against GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest JGit supports Apache MINA which can use ECDSA keys without problems.

Be wary that JGit 6.x is build for Java 11+. Use the following Maven artifacts:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0.202109080827-r</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0.202109080827-r</version>
        </dependency>
```

No code changes were needed in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a fork of JSch](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch) which has support for modern algorithms and should be fairly robust.  I know of at least one major organization using it against GitHub with success.

However, note that it disables RSA with SHA-1 support by default, because it's insecure (which is why GitHub is phasing it out), so if you need to work with sites that don't support anything else (e.g., Azure DevOps at the moment), you'll need to set some configuration accordingly.

You may also be able to use Apache Mina in conjunction with JGit.  The 5.13 release of JGit supports Mina 2.7.0, which should support modern algorithms.

Comment: This fork seems to have different package names so unless there's also a fork of JGit which can use it, I guess it won't work.

Comment: It's possible you might be able to convince the JGit team to support that fork.  Otherwise, at the moment, my suggestion is to use command-line Git.

Comment: https://github.com/mwiede/jsch/issues/85 OPEN :(

Comment: I've also edited to include Apache MINA, which is an alternate implementation which should support modern algorithms.